# Pass parameter between scikit learn pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have the following pipelines that extract certain columns from a dataframe then apply a simpleimputer.

The problem is that sometimes the columns will not existed in the dataframe therefore, there is no need to run the next step pipeline.

Is there a way to pass a parameter/argument between each step, e.g., skill_next, to the pipeline steps to skip it.

```
Pipeline ([
    ('extract', extract_feature(dataframe['categoricals]),
    ('fill', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='dummy')

])
```

Is it possible to have something like

```
Pipeline ([
    ('extract', extract_feature(dataframe['categoricals]),
    ('fill', WrapSimpleImputer(skip=a_parameter_that_can_be_passed_depending_on_the_previous_step_results, strategy='constant', fill_value='dummy')

])
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419380/how-to-pass-values-between-steps-of-a-scikit-learn-pipeline where it looks like the answer is 'no.'

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply. Yes, by default pipeline behavior, it will not support passing parameters. I am looking for a workaround/hack to achieve this goal. I have come up with some way and might work, but i need more tests to confirm. The trick is how to let the pipeline set the parameter to drop/passthrough

Comment: Yes. The link above has a hack that may be helpful.